# Quadratic Equation - I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Tags: quadratics

So I am learning Quadratic Equations and I have learned about the Formulas for calculating the Delta $(\Delta)$ and $x_1$, $x_2$.

I have this equation $$x^2 - 10x + 15 = 0$$ and I've tried to do my best but it turns out that I have the wrong result on $x_2$ according to [cymath.com](http://cymath.com).

Could someone explain what I've done wrong ?

> $x^2-10x+15=0$
>
> $\Delta = b^2-4ac=100-4\times 15=100-60$
>
> $\Delta = 40$
>
> $\Delta > 0$
>
> $x=\dfrac{-(b)\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2a}$
>
> $x_1=\dfrac{-(-10)+\sqrt\Delta}{2}=\dfrac{10+\sqrt\Delta}{2} = 8.16$
>
> $x_2=\dfrac{-(-10)-\sqrt\Delta}{2}=\dfrac{10-\sqrt\Delta}{2} = 3.67$

Comment: You seem to have only made an arithmetic mistake. $\frac{10 - \sqrt{40}}{2} \approx{} 1.84$. I think you forgot to divide by 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't divide by $2$
$$10-\sqrt{40}\approx 3.67$$
Now you were asked for
$$\frac{10-\sqrt{40}}{2}\approx\frac{3.67}{2}=1.835$$

Comment: :D HHHHH Thnx alot. I must have forgot to do that xD

Comment: @IdontReallywolf No problem,sometimes it happens to me too  :P